# How can I make my AVR remote work while I'm about 100’ away from AVR?

Tags: home-theater

[image]

My main TV is in the living room (upstairs), with speakers while my AVR Denon is in my basement which is about 100’ away. I don’t know much about IR extension. I need to make sure I can use my remote to my Denon while I am upstairs. What tool do I need to buy to achieve that?

AVR **AVRX6500H**

Back Panel
https://manuals.denon.com/AVRX6500H/NA/EN/DNTXSYultsfrsy.php

Comment: I simply added an IR LED to a wifi-connected MCU and pointed it at my rack. It lets me control all the things from anywhere in the house and easily define macros like "movie mode" which turns on projector, switches amp, and dims lights. Well worth the $5...

Answer (score 3):

You already mentioned it in your question, it's an IR (infrared) "extension" or "repeater". There are dozens of models available, find one that does what you need (extends for 100 feet or meters). Wired and wireless models are available.

These absorb infrared signals from your remote and retransmit them at the other end, so you'd put one end near your TV and the other end in your AVR location.

Comment: Yup, this. Some need dedicated wiring, some can piggyback the signal in an HDMI cable, and I'm sure there are dozens of other options, too. Of course, if OP's really running 100m, he's already got HDMI extenders and many of those have IR repeating built right in.

Comment: I have plenty of cat6 running it my house I have 2 behind TV to the rack in the basement. It blocks by 2 walls and 1 door.

Comment: @cyb3rZ is this, in some ay, an impediment to implementing any of the off-the-shelf IR repeaters on the market? If so, edit that into your original question, otherwise, I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Is there an IR extender that can piggy back off of cat6 cables ? I have direct connections from rack to TV. 120’ plus. I used one for cat6 - hdmi and I still have one left.

Comment: @cyb3rZ that is a shopping question and those are off-topic. I'm sure there are. If you've got HDMI over Ethernet extenders, there are definitely IR repeaters that will work with those (we have them at our church). As the saying goes, though, finding the best one for you "is an exercise left for the reader". ;)

Comment: Ok. I’ll just buy a bunch and test each one and return what I don’t keep.